# Unexpected Behavior of :even pseudo selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have created this fiddle for problem as you will see there are three tables having zebra strip using jQuery.

Table 1 is showing in correct form as it start tr index from 0 as even. Table 2 is continuing from last table and it is showing 1st row as white instead of dark. I think it is happening due to it is continuing from last table's tr index.

*HTML:*

```
<table>
    <caption> Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <caption> Table 2</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <caption> Table 3</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$('table').find('tr:even').css('background','#d0d0d0');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daljir/gryh5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to 'work' with each table separately:

```
$("table").find("tr:even").css("background", "#d0d0d0");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gryh5/1/

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting all the `<tr>` elements in the document, you can use the `nth-child` to selector to select all the even numbered `<tr>`s in the document.

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2n)').css('background','#d0d0d0');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/gryh5/7/

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are selecting all the tr's in general (irrespective of the table) and when they are stacked you would get this particular behavior.
Try this:

```
$('table').find('tr:even').css('background','#d0d0d0');
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gryh5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<table id="t1">
    <caption> Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="t2">
    <caption> Table 2</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="t3">
    <caption> Table 3</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 1</th>
        <td>Table Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 2</th>
        <td>Table Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Head 3</th>
        <td>Table Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#t1 tr:even, #t2 tr:even, #t3 tr:even').css('background','#d0d0d0');
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/gryh5/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gryh5/9/

```
$('table').each(function(){
   $(this).find('tr').filter(':even').css('background','#d0d0d0');
});
```